# How to Save DataFrame to Excel file using filedialouge in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can we write `DataFrame` object of `Pandas` using `filedialouge` in python `tkinter`.

```
file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".xlsx")
data.to_excel(file)
```

Whenever I try to write it it gives me error.

```
stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

I have been searching this error for hours, but the solutions are not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".xlsx")
```

[`tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename) will return filename as string, not file object like `tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfile`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `str`:

```
data.to_excel(str(file) + '.xlsx')
```

Comment: It's not working still.

Comment: @kanwarprogrammer What's the error?